# Do bitcoin mining trade company ask a lot of fees? before transaction

Tags: transactions

Please, please, Please Please answer anyone. Can please anyone tell me is there are a ton of fees to be paid before transferring the btc profit to bank account?

I feel I got scammed by a woman who runs a btc trading company,
im3trad.com is the company where she asked me to make an account a broker account, and she asked me to invest in btc, i paid 10k(100$) initially, then she asked me pay for frozen account, 1050$, then she showed me profit in the broker account to be 20000$ and asked me to pay 2050$ for net dips -- idk what net dips is , then later she told me that you have to pay surcharges 2250$ as 5% of commission I paid that also, later, now she asked for KYC verification fee to be 2800$.

I am very tensed, I am no longer paying her, but is these all-necessary payments for getting btc to bank account?? please please answer.